# Adding an entry to OpenLDAP

Tags: ldap, openldap

I just Installed OpenLDAP on Ubuntu Server 12.10, and I added an ldif file using `slapadd -c -l init.ldif` as the following :

```
dn:dc=tpw,dc=uca,dc=ma
dc: tpw
objectClass: dcObject
objectClass: top
objectClass: domain

dn: ou=people,dc=tpw,dc=uca,dc=ma
ou: people
objectClass: organizationalUnit
objectClass: top

dn: ou=groupes,dc=tpw,dc=uca,dc=ma
ou: groupes
objectClass: organizationalUnit
objectClass: top

dn: uid=admin,ou=people,dc=tpw,dc=uca,dc=ma
uid: admin
sn: Admin
cn: Admin
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: person
objectClass: top
userPassword:: e1NIQX0wRFBpS3VOSXJyVm1EOElVQ3V3MWhReE5xWmM9
mail: admin@uca.ma
givenName: admin

dn: cn=GI,ou=groupes,dc=tpw,dc=uca,dc=ma
uniquemember: uid=admin,ou=people,dc=tpw,dc=uca,dc=ma
cn: GI
objectClass: groupOfUniqueNames
objectClass: top

dn: cn=GP,ou=groupes,dc=tpw,dc=uca,dc=ma
uniquemember: uid=admin,ou=people,dc=tpw,dc=uca,dc=ma
cn: GP
objectClass: groupOfUniqueNames
objectClass: top

dn: cn=GT,ou=groupes,dc=tpw,dc=uca,dc=ma
uniquemember: uid=admin,ou=people,dc=tpw,dc=uca,dc=ma
cn: GT
objectClass: groupOfUniqueNames
objectClass: top
```

Now my ldap tree looks like this :

[image]

Then I tried to add a new `inetOrgPerson` using `Apache Directory Studio`, but I got this error :

```
  [LDAP: error code 80 - index generation failed]
```

Then I tried the same thing using `phpLDAPadmin`, but I got this error :

```
Impossible d'ajouter l'objet au serveur LDAP.
LDAP dit :: Other (e.g., implementation specific) error
Erreur numéro ::    0x50 (LDAP_OTHER)
```

Then I created a file which I named `xx.ldif` :

```
dn: uid=xx,ou=people,dc=tpw,dc=uca,dc=ma
cn: XX
givenname: xx
mail: xx@edu.uca.ma
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: person
objectclass: top
sn: XX
uid: xx
userpassword: toor
```

And I tried to add this entry using this command via terminal :

```
sudo ldapadd -x -D cn=Manager,dc=tpw,dc=uca,dc=ma -W -f xx.ldif
```

But I got this error :

```
ldap_add: Other (e.g., implementation specific) error (80)
        additional info: index generation failed
```

How can I solve this problem ?

PS : In another scenario I deleted my database and I modified the file init.ldif wich contains all the entries I want to add, and I added the entry xx, then I imported my file using the slapadd command, but In this way I have to delete the database every time I want to add a new entry, which is not practical.

## Edit1 :

This is the output of the command `slapindex` :

```
WARNING!
Runnig as root!
There's a fair chance slapd will fail to start.
Check file permissions!

5370d6f9 /etc/ldap/slapd.conf: line 95: rootdn is always granted unlimited privileges.
5370d6f9 /etc/ldap/slapd.conf: line 112: rootdn is always granted unlimited privileges.
5370d6f9 hdb_db_open: database "dc=tpw,dc=uca,dc=ma": database already in use.
5370d6f9 backend_startup_one (type=hdb, suffix="dc=tpw,dc=uca,dc=ma"): bi_db_open failed! (-1)
slap_startup failed
```

Comment: I think you need to stop slapd and run slapindex.

Comment: @EJP , please check the modification I made to my post.

Comment: This question is off topic here and belongs on serverfault.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing is that init.ldif file seems to be misconfigured :

- **domainComponent** "uca" (dc=uca) is missing, there should be an entry (*dcObject* or *domain* objectClass) to define this attribute that holds a component of the domain name.
- **dcObject** is intended to be used in entries for which there is an appropriate structural object class. For example, if the domain represents a particular organization, the entry would have as its structural object class 'organization', and the 'dcObject' class would be an auxiliary class.
- **domain** is a structural object class used for entries in which no other information is being stored. The domain object class is typically used for entries that are placeholders or whose domains do not correspond to real-world entities.

In your .ldif file you can replace the first entry "dn: dc=tpw,dc=uca,dc=ma" with these 2 (then delete your database again and redo the slapadd command) :

```
dn: dc=uca,dc=ma
objectClass: top
objectClass: organization
objectClass: dcObject    
dc: uca
o: an organization name (mandatory with 'organization' objectClass)

dn: dc=tpw,dc=uca,dc=ma
objectClass: top
objectClass: domain
dc: tpw
```

Second thing : obviously you have landed into an index issue. I think you do want to use indexes but if not, find and remove any line beginning with `index` from slapd.conf, e.g. :
`index  objectClass eq`.

Remember to stop slapd and run `slapindex` after every change comitted to the index definitions in slapd.conf, and ensure all ldap clients have been disconnected before running slap commands to prevent `database already in use` messages.

Answer (score 1):

So take the hints given you by slapindex. Don't run slapd as root, fix lines 95 and 112, and don't run slapd twice, or fix whatever is causing it to think the database is already in use.

Answer (score 1):

While this isn't relevant to the OP's question, I ran into a similar error of:

`bdb_db_open: database already in use`

or

`hdb_db_open: database "dc=XXX,dc=XXX,dc=XXX": database already in use.`

One of our Openshift nodes went down and the PVC's (mount) `/var/lib/ldap/` __db.001, __db.002 and __db.003 had become locked.  After googling for hours, the only solution I found was to perform the following (and note, since it was OpenShift, I had to use a debug pod to get a shell).

`mkdir /var/lib/ldap/backup`

`mv /var/lib/ldap/__db.* /var/lib/ldap/backup`

Try and restart slapD, if it still fails as it did with one of OpenLDap instances, then move the alock file

`mv /var/lib/ldap/__db.* /var/lib/ldap/backup`

Restart slapD or in our instance delete the OpenShift pod and let it be recreated.  Everything may now be working as it did for us - hope this might help anyone else running into the same issue.